# Java 8 Socket Example Style Confusion (KnockKnockServer)

Tags: java, sockets, exception

I'm reading through the KnockKnockServer example:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class KnockKnockServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.err.println("Usage: java KnockKnockServer <port number>");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        int portNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        try ( 
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            PrintWriter out =
                new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        ) {

            String inputLine, outputLine;

            // Initiate conversation with client
            KnockKnockProtocol kkp = new KnockKnockProtocol();
            outputLine = kkp.processInput(null);
            out.println(outputLine);

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                outputLine = kkp.processInput(inputLine);
                out.println(outputLine);
                if (outputLine.equals("Bye."))
                    break;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception caught when trying to listen on 
                port" + portNumber + " or listening for a connection");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

My question regards exception handling. Firstly, why does the main method/function have a throws clause associated with it? To my knowledge any IOException will be dealt with in the corresponding catch block and not forwarded up the chain.

Secondly, it is my understanding that accepting a socket connection, and attempting to read from an active/created connection may throw IOExceptions. Is it better to try and handle acceptance of the connection separately from attempts to read from it, or is this particular style "kosher"?

Comment: The error handling here is non-existent to keep the example code small.  This is done by having `main` declare that it throws the `IOException` instead of handling it properly itself. -- no I'm wrong.  The catch clause catches the exceptions. -- it probably was written first with no exception handling, which was added later, and the throws declaration was never removed.

Comment: Accepting the connection is followed by a 4 statement while loop for processing.  Separating this into 2 distinct functions may or may not make the code cleaner, easier to understand/ maintain.  It is a question of style and/or opinion.

Comment: "*Is it better to try and handle acceptance of the connection separately from attempts to read from it*" - This depends on your requirements. But generally, yes, it's best to keep error handling for read/write separate from accepting connections. If this program allowed multiple connections, an exception from a read/write would wind up closing the `ServerSocket`, no longer allowing connections. Same for reading & writing: if there's an exception when writing, you won't be able to read any more data, since the `catch` would be triggered.